# Suppose $f\geq0$ is an integrable function defined on $\Omega$ such that $f^n$ is integrable then show that $f=\varkappa_E$ a.e

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on a set $\Omega$. Suppose that $f\geq0$ is an integrable function defined on $\Omega$ such that $f^n$ is integrable $\forall n=1,2,3,\ldots$ and $$\int_{\Omega}f^nd\mu=\int_{\Omega}fd\mu.$$
Show that $f=\varkappa_E$ a.e for some $E\subset \Omega$.

Comment: What does $f^n$ denote?

Comment: @user6247850 Presumably, $f^n$ is $f$ multiplied by itself $n$ many times.

Comment: yes it's nice. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the one hand, by monotone convergence
$$
\int_{\{f>1\}}f^n\,d\mu\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\infty\cdot\mu(f>1)
$$

On the other, by the assumptions in the OP
$$
\int_{\{f>1\}}f^n\,d\mu\leq \int f\,d\mu,\qquad n\in\mathbb{N}
$$

Hene $\mu(f>1)=0$ and so $f=f\mathbb{1}_{\{f\leq1\}}$ $\mu$-a.s.

By dominated convergence
$$
\int_{\{f<1\}}f^n\,d\mu\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0
$$

Hence
$$
\int f\,d\mu = \int f^n\,d\mu=\int_{\{f<1\}}f^n\,d\mu +\mu(f=1)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu(f=1)
$$

Con you finish from here?

Comment: hello Oliver,  how did you conclude in the third line $\mu(f>1)=0$. And for the Dominated convergence theorem, you need a bounded function. Is your bounded function is $1$?

Comment: @ShanOH: because if $\mu(f>1)$, then  $\int f$  would be infinity ($\int f =\int f^n \geq \int_{\{f>1\}}f^n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\infty$) contradicting the integrability of $f$.

Comment: oh. I see now. since $\int{f}d\mu$ is finite, $\int_{f>1}{f^n} d\mu$ should be finite. but by the MCT $\int_{f>1}{f^n} d\mu$ is $\infty.\mu(f>1)$. thererfore $\mu{f>1}$ should be zero. That makes sense. Thank you

Comment: So my $f=\varkappa_E$ where $E$={$x\in \Omega \ such that\  f(x)=1$}